# Celery task starts running before the flask app starts

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task

The `celery` task is starting even before the flask app is running.

I want to start a celery task when I make API call to a certain endpoint (eg: "/report"). So I started using `celery` for this. When I set up the `celery` app and when I run the "celery -A app worker -l info" command. The `celery` task started executing, even before my flask app is live. But I want to start a task when I make an API call to the endpoint. My `run.py` is given as:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from celery import Celery
from report_main import generate_report

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])

global machine_id, scan_id, org_id



@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Report generation"

@app.route("/home")
def home_home():
    return jsonify(
        listening="The model is live"
    )

@app.route("/report", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload():
    global machine_id, scan_id, org_id
    machine_id = request.args.get("machine_id")
    scan_id = request.args.get("scan_id")
    org_id = request.args.get("org_id")

    task = intiate_report_generation.delay(org_id, machine_id, scan_id)

    return jsonify(
        success="Report Generation Initiated",
        task_id=task.id
    )

@celery.task
def intiate_report_generation(org_id, machine_id, scan_id):

    report_url, heatmap_urls = generate_report(org_id, machine_id, scan_id)
    # Do something with the report_url and heatmap_urls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: This probably happened because you stopped worker before previously ran tasks were executed, so they stayed in the queue. Next time you run worker it will start executing those tasks that. It would have happened even if you did not start flask at all. If you do not want this, then purge the queue(s) before you start worker.

Comment: How can I purge the queues?

Comment: One way is to use the `purge` command. ( Run `celery --help` to see more, or read online documentation)